# Django: Filter on model column with Regex

Tags: django, postgresql

I have phone numbers stored as (921) 414-1313 in the database and I want to run a search lookup on that field, but I don't want to force them to include (, ' ', ) or -.

I'm using Postgres and tried to work with SearchVector initially, however it ran into the same challenge (so for now, I'm doing it the old fashioned way).

I have a model definition that returns an "unformatted" number as 9214141313, but I can't figure out how to query against my custom definition inside of the model?

Ultimately, I want a customer to be able to type in 921414 and get the response for the matching record.

GitHub:
https://github.com/varlenthegray/wcadmin/blob/dev/main/views.py#L25

Model:

```py
class JobSite(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quickbooks_id = models.IntegerField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    print_on_check_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    service_interval = models.IntegerField(default=12)
    next_service_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    primary_technician = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    access_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    bill_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    requires_supporting_technician = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    service_scheduled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    disable_service = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    qb_created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    def phone_digits_only(self):
        return re.sub("[^0-9]", "", self.phone_number)

    @property
    def is_past_due(self):
        ignore_after = timezone.localdate() - relativedelta(years=5)

        # noinspection StrFormat
        if self.next_service_date:
            if ignore_after >= self.next_service_date:
                return False
            else:
                return timezone.localdate() > self.next_service_date
        else:
            return False

    @property
    def is_due_soon(self):
        ignore_after = timezone.localdate() - relativedelta(years=3)

        if self.next_service_date and self.next_service_date >= ignore_after:
            three_months_future = timezone.localdate() + relativedelta(months=2)
            return three_months_future > self.next_service_date
        else:
            return False
```

Views.py

```py
def search_system(request, search_term=False):
    if search_term:
        job_sites = JobSite.objects.filter(
            Q(first_name__icontains=search_term) |
            Q(last_name__icontains=search_term) |
            Q(quickbooks_id__icontains=search_term) |
            Q(email__icontains=search_term) |
            Q(phone_number_digits=search_term)
        )
    else:
        job_sites = JobSite.objects.all().prefetch_related('customer')

    data = []

    for job in job_sites:
        if job.first_name and job.last_name:
            name = job.first_name + ' ' + job.last_name
        elif job.customer.company:
            name = job.customer.company
        else:
            name = job.customer.first_name + ' ' + job.customer.last_name

        this_job = {'value': name}

        data.append(this_job)

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution IMHO is to use the library [phonenumbers](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/) which is very cleaned and well maintained.

Then do a custom "`phone_cleaned`" field where you add the signals "create" and "update" for this model, and update `phone_cleaned` accordingly (using the library to clean the phone number). And use that `phone_cleaned` to do all your searches.

Comment: I didn't use this in my solution, but this seems like the best solution. Thanks Oliver!